# How can i return back the id from a post method using php?

Tags: php

I need to go back to the page id after update. How can I get back the id.

```
    <?php
    include '/dbconn.php';
    $title=  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']);
    $body=  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['body']);
    $ID=  mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['save']);
    $sql="UPDATE itemDB SET title='$title', body='$body' WHERE ID='$ID'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    // Is where I need your help
    // I tried this echo ID; but it's still not working
    header('location:././lookup.php?ItemID=$ID');
    ?>
```

Error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\saving.php on line 10

Comment: You should use double quotes in the `header()` instead of single quotes

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions, they are deprecated. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: the code you posted doesn't support the error.

Comment: How can i know which one to use am new with php

Answer (score 0):

You have to use double-quotes ("), otherwise $ID won't be replaced. Also, `././` as a path doesn't make that much sense to me.

Try it with `header("Location: lookup.php?ItemID=$ID");` (if it's in the same directory)